# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON как исправить

Tags: json

Откопал бота для дискорда, но проблема не приходит одна.

после команды `yarn start`

Консоль ругается так:

```
SyntaxError: c:\Mafia\config.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 92
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1227:39)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Mafia\bot.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module.m._compile (c:\Mafia\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Содержимое **config.json**:

```
{
    "token": "MTA1MzI5OTQ4OTA3MjQ4NDM4Mg.GFKuGm.En-mxtnKfP23-fIZHdN_SVEednYDOMBE7dJgOw", // your bot's token
    "prefix": "!", // for example "%"
    "client_id": "443851143043350538",
    "public_key": "e47348cba6488c98b3f6b193190ec91c6894647888cc4f35c4b3c2e85ff5f5bd",
    "PLAYERS_ROLES_ID": "1053319170026115162" // server defined role id for mafia players
}
```

На что ругается:

```
import { token, prefix } from "./config.json";

import {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Message,
  TextChannel,
  User,
  VoiceChannel,
} from "discord.js";
import randomise from "./commands/randomise";
```

Помогите починить эту шарманку пожалуйста :(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уберите комментарии из вашего JSON

Comment: @SwaD О боги, спасибо большое! Где тут +rep поставить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **JSON** формат не допускает комментарии.

**Удалите все комментарии из вашего JSON файла**